# who will be the owner of personal blog or website when joining a company

Tags: intellectual-property, ownership

I maintain a personal blog and about to join a new company. Under Intellectual Property Law, will my blog and new posts on it will be the property of my company or will it still belong to me?

Comment: What jurisdiction are you asking about? Does your employment contract say anything about it?  Will you be writing or posting new content while you are at work?

Comment: Juridiction is India bound, contract does not specifically says anything about blog or website but referes to any piece of art, idea, software etc. I plan to keep posting on it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing this blog in your personal capacity and not as a representative of the company, given that you have written this before joining the company, you will be the owner of the copyright of that blog. However, if it is stated in your contract that any articles you publish after joining the company become a copyright of that company, then all articles you subsequently publish (not the ones you have already published) become a copyright of the company. Read [Chapter IV of the Indian Copyright Act, 1957](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiRv6b_n93TAhVHPY8KHdtaAIAQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcopyright.gov.in%2Fdocuments%2Fcopyrightrules1957.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF9pkDw4VOi2qo8SYo8U7pFp88XEA&sig2=OK_RWJDhF91_ISVUORfz_Q) for more details.